# Ошибка сегментации. Какова природа?

Tags: c++

В результате исполнения этого кода - у программы возникает ошибка сегментации.
Подскажите какова ее природа?

Порядок вызова методов

```
trainData obj;
obj.getSize(size);
obj.setData(inputArray);
obj.getData();
```

Исполнительный файл

```
void trainData::setData(int inputArray[])
{
    int *incomeData = new int [mySize];
    for (int i=0;i<mySize;i++)
    {
        incomeData[i] = inputArray[i];
    }
}
/**
    Функция которая будет получать размер входящих данных.
*/
void trainData::getSize(int size)
{
    mySize = size;
}
/**
    Вывод данных
*/
void trainData::getData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mySize; i++)
    {

        cout << incomeData[i] << " "; <- тут возникает ошибка сегментации
    }
}
```

Файл с заголовками

```
class trainData
{
public:
    trainData();
    ~trainData();
    void setData(int*);
    void getData();
    void getSize(int);

private:
    int *incomeData[];
    int mySize;
};
```

Comment: Природа не ясна, поскольку что есть myData вы не указали, порядок вызова методов тоже.

Comment: Кусочек ненужного кода забыл удалить. так правильно.

Comment: Нигде в Вашем коде Вы не присваиваете полю `incomeData` какого-либо значения.

Comment: Я ему присваиваю значения 'inputArray[]'

Comment: Не ему вы присываиваете. Не ему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int *incomeData = new int [mySize];` - локальное объявление переменной, а `cout << incomeData[i]` - обращение к полю класса, которое не инициализировано. Вот и природа. Осваивайте отладчик, пришло время.

Comment: Абсолютно точно. И лучше бы это все сделать в конструкторе.

Comment: @Ximerik, разобрались, что у Вас локальная переменная `int *incomeData` в функции `trainData::setData` перекрывает одноимённое поле класса `trainData`? Если напишете так: `incomeData = new int [mySize];` (т.е. без `int *`) должно сработать.

Comment: Разобрался. Реализовал через конструктор.